# CognitoUser does not contain a constructor that contain 4 arguments error and no definition for StartWithSrpAuthAsync at ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to use Cognito Sign In for my application at ASP.NET C# and I have managed to make the user sign up. However, when I am trying to implement the codes for Sign In there are 2 errors at these lines below :

```
CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(username,ClientID,userPool,provider);
```

this line result in "CognitoUser does not contain a constructor that contain 4 arguments error"

and the 2nd error at this part :

```
authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

this line result in "CognitoUser does not contain definition for StartWithSrpAuthAsync and No Extension Method…accepting a first argument of type ” could be found" error

This is my full code :

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentity;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm5 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        const string PoolID = "poolid";
        const string ClientID = "clientid";
        static Amazon.RegionEndpoint Region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = "user1";
            string password = "pass";
            string email = "email1";
            SignInUser(username,password);
        }
        static async Task SignInUser(string username, string password)
        {
            AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials(), Region);

            CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(PoolID, ClientID, provider);

            CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(username,ClientID,userPool,provider);

            InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
            {
                Password = password
            };

            AuthFlowResponse authResponse = null;
            try
            {
                authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Logon Failed: {0}\n", ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            GetUserRequest getUserRequest = new GetUserRequest();
            getUserRequest.AccessToken = authResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: It sounds like some features are not installed. Did you install Cognito via Nuget, your should also check its dependencies, and also make sure you registered it in **Startup.cs**

Comment: My project is ASP.NET C# and there is no StartUp.cs file. For the dependencies, I need to install the older version for all Amazon Cognito at Nuget due to the error with the Cognito Authentication Extensions if I install the newer version. Does it cause the error or there might be any other problem?

Comment: I've read here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html#API_UploadPart_ResponseSyntax that the MD5 is auto filled via CLI and I think the C# lib is doing the same job as the CLI. You may need to calculate the MD5 yourself and add it to parameters ... I hope it figure in the list of arguments in the C# upload method

Comment: Concerning the lack of **Startup.cs** you may need to upgrade your project, it should address your second issue about `StartWithSrpAuthAsync`, also you absolutely need to update your packages, I'm not familiar with Cognito but I think that they could have addressed all your issues in their very last version or beta ones

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found out that I need to use newer Visual Studio in order to solve the line issues.